# Topologist Sine Curve

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove that the topologist sine curve is not path connected. I think I have a 
proof but my proof relies on Intermediate Value Theorem. So, I was wondering if there is a way 
to prove it without using Intermediate Value Theorem.

Thank You.

Comment: A google search turns up this http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/diffgeomPage/handouts/sinecurve.pdf

Comment: What's wrong with using the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury I am in a topology class. Most of us know about the intermediate value theorem but we have not covered it in class yet.

Comment: Do you know how to prove the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury Yes I do. I suppose you are suggesting that I should prove the  intermediate value theorem as part of the entire proof.

Comment: The intermediate value theorem is just a special case of the fact that a continuous image of a connected set is connected; have you proved that more general result?